# Java Elastic limit post execiton time

Tags: java, post, elasticsearch

I do post like this:

```
 Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("cluster.name", "cluster-name")
                        .build();

                client = TransportClient.builder()
                        .settings(settings)
                        .build();

                client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("my.elastic.server"), 9300));

                IndexResponse response = client
                        .prepareIndex("myindex", "info")
                        .setSource(data) //here data is stored in a Map
                        .get();
```

But `data` could be about 2Mb or more and I care about the speed it would be posted to elastic. What is the best way to limit that time? Such `Elastic Java API` feature or maybe run posting in a separate `Thread` or maybe something else? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize [Spring Data Elasticsearch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/) in Java and [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) to create an index batch job. This way you can break the data up into smaller chunks, for more frequent but smaller writes to your index.

If your job is big enough(millions of records), you can utilize a [multi-threaded batch job](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/), and significantly reduce the time it takes to generate your index. This may be overkill for a smaller index though.